# websockets running from django urls error: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to run this websocket script from django

```
async def get_cells(websocket, path):
  async for message in websocket:

    message = json.loads(message)
    ...
            if percentage % 5 == 0:
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({'complete': False, 'status': percentage}))
    ...

        await websocket.send(json.dumps({'complete': True, 'filename': filename}))
```

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(get_cells, 'localhost', 8765))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

I've saved is as path.py and in the urls imported it

```
import path
```

It's throwing this error

```
^C(pixelart) sam@sam-Lenovo-G51-35:~/code/pixelart$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f38e007f1e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/home/sam/code/envs/pixelart/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/sam/code/pixelart/pixelart/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    import path
File "/home/sam/code/pixelart/path.py", line 55, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 694, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 602, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.
```

### Suggestion

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    websockets.serve(get_cells, 'localhost', 8765))

asyncio.get_event_loop(loop).run_forever()
```

this suggestion returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You may have been putting the path of your URL import according to where your path.py file is located.

You have to put the path according to where manage.py file is located.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yeah, I actually forgot to save changes to urls.py that's why it wasn't working or throwing any error. Now it's actually throwing one.

Comment: are you using a scheduler anywhere else in the program?

Answer (score 0):

Try and save

> asyncio.get_event_loop()

in variable, like

> var = asyncio.get_event_loop()

and use

> asyncio.set_event_loop(var)

Comment: I'm sorry. You've to use "set_event_loop" in the end

Comment: even with that change it still returns the same error.